# How do I change my .class into .java on Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've finished my Java assignment on Netbeans, however the files are .class. If I understand correctly this means they have been compiled using javac into bytecode? I'm sorry, I'm new to all of this. However I must submit this is in .java format. If I just rename the file it doesn't open properly, is there proper procedure using Netbeans or something? (I'm on windows 10, Netbeans 8.2).

Sorry if this is a really noobish question and I'm being stupid! It's always the tiny things I get stuck on. Thanks.

Comment: You have editied `.java` files in netbeans, so they are somwhere on your filesystem (maybe in a *src* folder).

Comment: @Andreas_D thank you! Yes this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your source code in *.java files, then they must be compiled to *.class, bytecode. This bytecode you can run on JVM: java "name of file without .class suffix".

If you want to change your *.class file, you must change *.java file, then compile again to *.class.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, problem solved.